# My villager has one trade and it is locked. Is that a glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I locked this villager's only trade and it won't unlock! It has been like that for a few hours. I logged out and back in too. Is that a glitch?

[image: one locked trade]

Comment: logging out and back in isn't going to help, neither is waiting. I'd kill the villager and hope it doesn't happen again with the next one.

Comment: I've noticed that there is a certain amount of trades you can make with a villager, once you have used up all these trades, the villager trading is useless. This was changed as of 14w02a where after a short while villagers will reopen their trades.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but the right-most trade might also be wheat.  If it is wheat, do the trade once and the left option should unlock.  Trades are normally only locked when a villager has 2 trades available, and doing the alternate one should unlock the other

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "locked?"

Comment: @Seb that's why I'm confused, since there is only one trade available and this is it.@DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms, what I mean by "locked" is that it has the red x and it won't allow me to trade with him.

Comment: Have you been able to trade with him? What happened before the "Lockout"?

Comment: I traded with him once. I traded wheat multiple times and got the emeralds for it. Then once it locked, it never unlocked and it is still like that.

Comment: And you cant click on the left or right arrows?

Comment: No I can't. They are both grayed out and clicking on them does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE: This is pre-1.14. Villager Trading Mechanics have now changed.**

So the thing is that this is a legit outcome. After a few trades (2 or 3) the villager will no longer be willing to trade that specific item with you. Generally this will however open more trades. Unfortunately, there is a minute possibility that this may be the only available trade this particular villager offers.

[image: Probability of being last offer]

> Note 3: This is the chance that the given trade offer will be the last one given by a villager when its options are completely exhausted.

Sorry to say you just got unlucky...

**EDIT** As per the comments, here are the mechanics on "re-enabling" locked/disabled trades.

- If a player trades the last offer on the list and closes the GUI, waiting for particles to appear around the villager, all disabled offers are renewed with 2-12 additional uses added to them.
- It is possible for the final offer slot to be disabled, at which point no new offers can be generated and no existing offers can be renewed.

Source: [Villager Trading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading)

**UPDATE:** In later versions<sup>[Version needed]</sup> of the game, some villagers (primarily browncoats) will not have *any* trades at all. Right-clicking will not open any UI to trade. The only purpose for these villagers is farming.

Comment: Nice answer! If you have a farmer villager, the probability of starting with wheat and having it be the last offer would be `16.0271% * .0005% = .0000801355%`. That means 1 in 1,247,886 farmer villagers are like this one.

Comment: **EDIT** Not just unlucky... Incredibly unlucky!