# Does NG+ and further boost item discovery rate?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So I have been trying to get Titanite Slabs. In effort to do this at the king's passage. I have been tossing bonefire ascetics into the bonfire there. It got to the point where the enemies half kill me every hit and I have not gotten a single Titanite slab yet.

Does increasing the ng+ boost item discovery?

Comment: How many Ascetics did you use??

Comment: my bonfire intensity is 16. So I guess 15?

Comment: Woooow... I... Wooooow.......

Comment: Oh the Horror of trying to farm Slabs at King's Passage. I would suggest either farming in Dragon Aerie (random%) or by farming Prowling Magnus & Congregation (1 guaranteed).

Comment: I found a slab. If you throw ascetics into Lower Brightstone Cove bonefire, there will be a room in the same building that has a dead body, on it is a slab. Also I think you can get a slab for defeating the boss or something, I got two slabs in total. Something else down there gives a second slab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The drop chance is affected purely by the player. Specifically what equipment they are using. Equipment such as the Golden Serpent ring, and the Jester Hat boost item discovery, and there are consumables that can also boost your item discovery temporarily.

The best method for farming these is to equip your best equipment to [boost your item discovery](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Item+Discovery)<sup>[1]</sup> and start farming. Kill each enemy until they stop spawning, *then* use an Ascetic to boost the Bonfire Intensity, and make the enemies respawn.

However, it is possible that you can [farm Titanite Slabs infinitely](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/titanite-slab) from the Stone Guards near the King's Gate Bonfire.

However, even with all of this there is no guarantee that you will get a drop, hence the term "chance". No matter how high the *chance* of getting what you want, there's always a *chance* that you won't, [no matter how small](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/168993/73976).

**EDIT:** For reference, [here](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/titanite-slab) is a list of all the locations, traders, mechanics, and enemies you can use to gain Titanite slabs. Remember, when you use a bonfire Ascetic, it *will* respawn items on corpses etc, but *not chests.*

---

<sup>[1]</sup> *"Burning Bonfire Ascetic does not affect item discovery or drop lists."*

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've recently played ng+ for the first time after beating the game three times with new characters, and a few hours into ng+ I feel like enemies are dropping items en masse although I'm not even wearing any item discovery increasing items. Every second to third enemy drops stuff now and just now a dwarf dropped three of his armour pieces at once. It actually feels similar to having the Gold Serpent ring and merchant's cap equipped before. I haven't found any research on that or claims that it increases so maybe it's just me, but it definitely feels different to me.

Comment: Yes I am. The thing about chance is that it's *chance*. Chance can be good or bad, but that's down to chance. It's like betting all in on a king high, but there's always a *chance* someone will have an ace high